Where is Postgres Update spending time and how to optimize it?
The table has close to 250 million records, and I am trying to update certain records. It takes close to 45s, and I just want to understand if there is a way to optimize it.
Query:
UPDATE commission
SET    knowledge_end_date = '2024-07-31T01:47:41.053562+00:00' :: timestamptz
WHERE  ( client_id = 93
         AND NOT is_deleted
         AND knowledge_end_date IS NULL
         AND payee_email_id = '*******'
         AND ( period_end_date BETWEEN
                     '2024-04-01T00:00:00+00:00' :: timestamptz AND
                     '2024-06-30T23:59:59.999999+00:00' :: timestamptz
                OR period_start_date BETWEEN
                   '2024-04-01T00:00:00+00:00' :: timestamptz AND
                       '2024-06-30T23:59:59.999999+00:00' :: timestamptz )
         AND criteria_id IN
             (
                 '354dec74-2f1e-4413-8c3e-ac3b2ffde584' ::
                 uuid
                 ,
                 '563f15a2-e5f8-46c0-94c3-65cec8e9f841' ::
                 uuid, '1f0626d9-5d5a-4781-8c34-2385b8c0edf0'
                 :: uuid,
             'e7d2fa13-383c-45ff-a9c1-55fb6c353634' :: uuid,
               'c017efdb-7774-4374-97ba-0a4938924945' :: uuid,
                 '6a9c6d90-a1ca-4af7-8a05-393f2314367a'
                 :: uuid,
                 '0afaf878-47e3-4845-8203-0d9dbdbe152a' :: uuid,
                 '4e459ae7-0868-4604-b4f3-62679a05db59'
                 ::
                                               uuid
                                               ,
                 '8953abd5-1881-4bf5-ba1a-34c03eeb6331'
                 ::
                 uuid
                 ) ) 

Query Plan
Update on public.commission  (cost=0.70..808370.78 rows=5690 width=650) (actual time=47317.841..47317.842 rows=0 loops=1)
      Update on public.commission_93
      Buffers: shared hit=2321291 read=13061 written=261
      I/O Timings: read=39525.082
      ->  Index Scan using commission_93_client_id_is_deleted_knowledge_end_date_payee_idx on public.commission_93  (cost=0.70..808370.78 rows=5690 width=650) (actual time=0.023..198.990 rows=62497 loops=1)
            Output: commission_93.temporal_id, commission_93.knowledge_begin_date, '2024-07-31 01:47:41.053562+00'::timestamp with time zone, commission_93.is_deleted, commission_93.additional_details, commission_93.period_start_date, commission_93.period_end_date, commission_93.payee_email_id, commission_93.commission_plan_id, commission_93.criteria_id, commission_93.line_item_type, commission_93.tier_id, commission_93.amount, commission_93.client_id, commission_93.commission_snapshot_id, commission_93.context_ids, commission_93.line_item_id, commission_93.primary_kd, commission_93.secondary_kd, commission_93.secondary_snapshot_id, commission_93.show_do_nothing, commission_93.commission_date, commission_93.original_tier_id, commission_93.ctid
            Index Cond: ((commission_93.client_id = 93) AND (commission_93.is_deleted = false) AND (commission_93.knowledge_end_date IS NULL) AND ((commission_93.payee_email_id)::text = '********'::text))
            Filter: ((((commission_93.period_end_date >= '2024-04-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (commission_93.period_end_date <= '2024-06-30 23:59:59.999999+00'::timestamp with time zone)) OR ((commission_93.period_start_date >= '2024-04-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (commission_93.period_start_date <= '2024-06-30 23:59:59.999999+00'::timestamp with time zone))) AND (commission_93.criteria_id = ANY ('{354dec74-2f1e-4413-8c3e-ac3b2ffde584,563f15a2-e5f8-46c0-94c3-65cec8e9f841,1f0626d9-5d5a-4781-8c34-2385b8c0edf0,e7d2fa13-383c-45ff-a9c1-55fb6c353634,c017efdb-7774-4374-97ba-0a4938924945,6a9c6d90-a1ca-4af7-8a05-393f2314367a,0afaf878-47e3-4845-8203-0d9dbdbe152a,4e459ae7-0868-4604-b4f3-62679a05db59,8953abd5-1881-4bf5-ba1a-34c03eeb6331}'::uuid[])))
            Rows Removed by Filter: 61754
            Buffers: shared hit=16983

Specifications:
Hardware specifications, OS and version for the 'machine'
db.r6g.2xlarge, AWS Aurora and version Postgres 12

Why are the buffer hits/reads higher between read (Buffers: shared hit=16983) and write (Buffers: shared hit=2321291 read=13061 written=261)?
How do we bring down the IO timing?
Can any config change be done at the Postgres level to speed up writes, like turning off replica sync or checkpoint etc.?


"Please" "remove" "all" "quotes". Please show table and index definitions.

To your question text add as text the answers to the following: 1) What are the hardware specifications for the 'machine' you are running this on? 2) OS and version?

public.commission vs public.commission_93, there is something going on that you didn't tell us. Any triggers, rules or other stuff that does something in the background?

@FrankHeikens The table is partitioned, commission_93 is a partition of commission

Presumably the buffer hits are mostly going to index maintenance, but since you haven't given us your table or index definitions we have no way of knowing.  How many indexes are on the table?

Try to....

reverse the NOT

cut you update in 2 to avoid the OR
UPDATE commission
SET    knowledge_end_date = '2024-07-31T01:47:41.053562+00:00' :: timestamptz
WHERE  ( client_id = 93
AND is_deleted is false
AND knowledge_end_date IS NULL
AND payee_email_id = ''
AND ( period_end_date BETWEEN
'2024-04-01T00:00:00+00:00' :: timestamptz AND
'2024-06-30T23:59:59.999999+00:00' :: timestamptz )
AND criteria_id IN
(
'354dec74-2f1e-4413-8c3e-ac3b2ffde584' ::
uuid
,
'563f15a2-e5f8-46c0-94c3-65cec8e9f841' ::
uuid, '1f0626d9-5d5a-4781-8c34-2385b8c0edf0'
:: uuid,
'e7d2fa13-383c-45ff-a9c1-55fb6c353634' :: uuid,
'c017efdb-7774-4374-97ba-0a4938924945' :: uuid,
'6a9c6d90-a1ca-4af7-8a05-393f2314367a'
:: uuid,
'0afaf878-47e3-4845-8203-0d9dbdbe152a' :: uuid,
'4e459ae7-0868-4604-b4f3-62679a05db59'
::
uuid
,
'8953abd5-1881-4bf5-ba1a-34c03eeb6331'
::
uuid
) );
UPDATE commission
SET    knowledge_end_date = '2024-07-31T01:47:41.053562+00:00' :: timestamptz
WHERE  ( client_id = 93
AND is_deleted is false
AND knowledge_end_date IS NULL
AND payee_email_id = ''
AND ( period_start_date BETWEEN
'2024-04-01T00:00:00+00:00' :: timestamptz AND
'2024-06-30T23:59:59.999999+00:00' :: timestamptz )
AND criteria_id IN
(
'354dec74-2f1e-4413-8c3e-ac3b2ffde584' ::
uuid
,
'563f15a2-e5f8-46c0-94c3-65cec8e9f841' ::
uuid, '1f0626d9-5d5a-4781-8c34-2385b8c0edf0'
:: uuid,
'e7d2fa13-383c-45ff-a9c1-55fb6c353634' :: uuid,
'c017efdb-7774-4374-97ba-0a4938924945' :: uuid,
'6a9c6d90-a1ca-4af7-8a05-393f2314367a'
:: uuid,
'0afaf878-47e3-4845-8203-0d9dbdbe152a' :: uuid,
'4e459ae7-0868-4604-b4f3-62679a05db59'
::
uuid
,
'8953abd5-1881-4bf5-ba1a-34c03eeb6331'
::
uuid
) ) ;


By the way, using a UUID as a key is a very bad idea which affects performance, especially in PostGreSQL that use 38 bytes (304 bits) for a UUID that is just a 128 bits binary information... !
Use INT/BIGINT instead, that are just one read into the processor that the word is limited to 64 bits...

use 38 bytes (304 bits) for a UUID eh? where did you get that from? `=> SELECT pg_column_size(gen_random_uuid());
┌────────────────┐
│ pg_column_size │
├────────────────┤
│             16 │
└────────────────┘
(1 row)


It depends on the way that are stored UUID, that is generally in text format, rarely in UUID one

Rarely in databases without a UUID type perhaps, but there's no good reason NOT to use uuid type in postgresql and the OP is doing so.
